# dependent name is not a type, templates with SFINAE

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, sfinae

I'm trying to register events like this:

```
void myResize(unsigned int width, unsigned int height);

int main() {
    registerEvent(Event::Resize, myResize);
}
```

Firstly, I tried to create an overload for every single event, but then I realized that won't work if there are two events with the same arguments, so I attempted to use templates and SFINAE.

After several hours of surfing the net, I got to minimally understand them.

Here's my last approach:

```
#include <type_traits>

enum class Event { Resize };

template<typename T>
struct enabler { typedef void type; };

template<Event, typename...>    
struct validate_event : std::false_type {};

template<Event Evt, typename T>
struct validate_event<Evt, T> : std::false_type {};

template<> //This is the only case when registerEvent should be validated
struct validate_event<Event::Resize, unsigned int, unsigned int> : std::true_type {};

template<Event Type, typename ...Args>
typename enabler<
    typename std::enable_if <
        validate_event<Type, Args...>::value // <-- Error Here
    > ::type
> ::type
registerEvent(Type type, void (*f)(Args...));
```

That approach is throwing several syntax errors (Since the "Error Here" Marked line and trough the whole stacktrace), and a warning, telling:

`'validate_event<__formal,<unnamed-symbol>...>::value': dependent name is not a type`.

After looking for the warning on internet, it seems like it's caused because a type isn't being defined as a `typename`.

Also tried using `value` instead of `type`, as they seem to be almost the same in [integral constants](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/integral_constant/) of type bool (As [true_type](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/true_type/) and [false_type](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/false_type/))

So, I would like to know whether I'm missing a typename somewhere, or why is the compiler failing to recognize `type` as a type.

Also, there must be an not so overcomplicated way to do this. I'm almost sure I'm just failing to see it. If there's any, could anyone give me an example of a similar case where that other approach is used?

Comment: `Event::Resize` isn't a type, it is a value of type `Event` which is the `Type` you are using in `registerEvent`, therefore it can never match `validate_event<Event::Resize, ...>`

Comment: the only occurence of `validate_event<Event::Resize, ...>` is a specification of `template<Event, typename...> struct validate_event...`, which is intented to be called only when the `Event` is `Event::Resize`. You can add values to specializations

Comment: ok, so `Type` is supposed to be `Event::Resize`... but then what is `type`? You're using `Type` as a type in the `registerEvent` signature, but it isn't, its a value. `Type type` doesn't make any sense when `Type` is a value.

Comment: you'll need to adopt the `register<Event::Resize>(callback)` syntax in order to do what you want.

Comment: Brilliant! I'd never had realized that. Removing `Type type` from arguments should suffice or the compiler won't be able to deduce `typename ...Args` by itself?

Comment: Removing `Type type` should work, the compiler can easily deduce `Args` from the function pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the point of `enable_if` here (and your `enabler` is not doing anything useful whatsoever). Just use specializations to map the event type to the desired function pointer signature, and use that as the parameter type directly:

```
template<Event> struct event_fn;

template<> struct event_fn<Event::Resize> {
    using type = void (*)(unsigned, unsigned); 
};
// other specializations

// alias template shorthand
template<Event Type> using event_fn_t = typename event_fn<Type>::type;

template<Event Type>
void registerEvent(event_fn_t<Type> f);
```

Compared to your approach (after fixes), this is cleaner when handling an overload set: because there is only one target type, the compiler can pick the right overload without requiring manual disambiguation:

```
void foo(unsigned, unsigned);
void foo();

registerEvent<Event::Resize>(foo); // OK with the above but not with the original
```